# How to add multiple lines in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to add multiple lines to a config file after a match and using the lineinfile but I am finding that the resulting lines are reversed. Here is my playbook:

```
  - name: Line test
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/vagrant/abcd
      insertafter: '### AFTER THIS LINE'
      line: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
    with_items:
      - '# This is line 1'
      - '# This is line 2'
      - '# This is line 3'
```

and here is the result:

```
### AFTER THIS LINE
# This is line 3
# This is line 2
# This is line 1
```

My desired result should be:

```
### AFTER THIS LINE
# This is line 1
# This is line 2
# This is line 3
```

I understand that the reversal is due to the loop but how can one overcome this without reversing the order of the input? I know there is the blockinfile which puts the block of text as-is but that adds the "ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK" markers which I don't want.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't do it, you don't need to (everyone at some point thought they needed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing a bit more on this I've discovered that I can do this:

```
 - name: Line test2
   blockinfile:
     path: /home/vagrant/abcd
     marker: "------"
     insertafter: '### AFTER THIS LINE PART 2'
     state: present
     block: |
       # This is line 1
       # This is line 2
       # This is line 3
```

Which produces this:

```
 ### AFTER THIS LINE PART 2
 ------
 # This is line 1
 # This is line 2
 # This is line 3
 ------
```

Which I think is acceptable for our requirements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with techraf's comment (and your answer) that blockinfile is better suited for this purpose. But I wanted to see how it could be done with lineinfile:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Add temp marker
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/vagrant/abcd
      insertafter: '### AFTER THIS LINE'
      line: "###TEMP MARKER###"
      state: present
  - name: Add content
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/vagrant/abcd
      insertbefore: '###TEMP MARKER###'
      line: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - '# This is line 1'
      - '# This is line 2'
      - '# This is line 3'
  - name: Remove temp marker
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/vagrant/abcd
      line: "###TEMP MARKER###"
      state: absent
```

Comment: Anyone knows how to achieve this for a Windows host?

Answer (score 0):

To answer @user2700022's question: on a Windows host I've managed to do it with the ansible windows collection's [`win_lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_lineinfile_module.html) module and the block character `|`:

```yaml
    - name: add mod_wsgi config to apache config
      win_lineinfile:
        path: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf
        line: |
          LoadFile "c:/python37/python37.dll"
          LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/software/env/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
          WSGIPythonHome "c:/software/env/"
        newline: windows
```